# Stored Procedure in azure sql database query tables in another azure sql database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have two azure databases say DB1 and DB2.
DB1 has got few tables and I want to create stored procedure in DB2 to cross query with joins in the tables in DB1. I have seen examples with Cross Database query but mostly showing only single table. My Stored procedure is like:

```
select
        u.UserID as [UserID],
        u.Username as [UserName],
        u.LastLoginDate,
        ISNULL(au.IsDeleted, 1) as [IsDeleted] 
from DB1.[sec].[User] u
join DB1.[sec].[AppUser] au on (u.UserID = au.UserID)
join DB1.[sec].[Application] a on (au.ApplicationID = a.ApplicationID)
where (a.Name = 'name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the method of [this blog post](https://www.scarydba.com/2016/03/21/cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-database/) and set up two tables instead of one. It's currently the only way to do a cross database query in Azure SQL Database.